# HTML 5 UI component markup libraries (like jQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markup, microformats

I have been using **jQuery Mobile** and love how with microformated HTML5 I get beautiful UI components and formatting. That is all you need to know is HTML and you can get great *immediate* look and feel which is awesome for **prototyping**.

I'm wondering if there are any other [microformat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat) UI component libraries that for non mobile sites?

*Clarification:*

When I say microformat I mean using structured and **semantic markup** with possibly some meta-data attributes to create **UI in a declarative fashion**.

There are some similar libraries but not really the same:

- DOJO (this may have changed) provides declaritive markup to create components.
- JSF libraries but this its server side and I'm looking for client side.
- Some jQuery UI widgets do but must of them are programmatic.
- XAML and XUL ... again like JSF and are not HTML.

There are many CSS libraries out there and almost all of them are about layout.

Comment: I don't really know of any others besides JQuery mobile, which utilizes the new html5 data attributes.  I feel this new feature will force some changes to the microformatting world.  Stay tuned I think we are going to see a lot more this in the near future.  We may start to see some this start to come into play with JQuery UI.  http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Microformatting seems like it is really more about data mining.  You seem to be looking or something more like this maybe.

http://www.blueprintcss.org/